# What is the most efficient way in JavaScript to parse huge amounts of data from a file

Tags: javascript, json, performance

What is the most efficient way in JavaScript to parse huge amounts of data from a file?

Currently I use JSON parse to serialize an uncompressed 250MB file, which is really slow. Is there a simple and fast way to read a lot of data in JavaScript from a file without looping through every character? The data stored in the file are only a few floating point arrays?

**UPDATE:**
The file contains a 3d mesh, 6 buffers (vert, uv etc). Also the buffers need to be presented as typed arrays. streaming is not a option because the file has to be fully  loaded before the graphics engine can continue. Maybe a better question is how to transfer huge typed arrays from a file to javascript in the most efficient way.

Comment: In the browser or in Node.js?

Comment: Why is the file so big and why does it have to be the browser?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend a SAX based parser for these kind of JavaScript or a stream parser.

DOM parsing would load the whole thing in memory and this is not the way to go by for large files like you mentioned.

`For Javascript based SAX Parsing (in XML)` you might refer to 
https://code.google.com/p/jssaxparser/

and

`for JSON` you might write your own, the following link demonstrates how to write a basic SAX based parser in Javascript
http://ajaxian.com/archives/javascript-sax-based-parser

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a really good way of doing that, because the whole file is going to be loaded into memory and we all know that all of them have big memory leaks. Can you not instead add some paging for viewing the contents of that file?

Check if there are any plugins that allow you to read the file as a stream, that will improve this greatly.

**UPDATE**

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

You might want to read about the new HTML5 API's to read local files. You will have the issue with downloading 250mb of data still tho.

Comment: "We all know that all of them have big memory leaks"?  [citation required]

Comment: It is my own citation, given my experience :)

Comment: But this will help you in case you wondering: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/173627/why-do-browsers-leak-memory

Comment: Your experience seems rather odd to me.  I hardly ever close Chrome, and its memory usage never seems to get outrageous.  I would think after a few weeks, the browser would just up and die from all these "big memory leaks".  :P

Comment: Does it? Hmm, maybe then the version of chrome you use is different from everyone else: https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chrome/tSydCScdDho

Comment: Sometimes a simple google query helps to clear out any doubts:https://www.google.ie/search?q=chrome+memory+leak

Comment: The 250 mb is the uncompressed worste case filesize. not the size the user has to download.

Comment: Ok, but still without knowing your business requirements a would try to add "pagination" to that data.

Comment: @Marco: It seems a bit less than coincidental that Chrome crashed shortly after clicking your link... :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried encoding it to a binary and transferring it as a blob?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/working-with-binary-files-using-the-javascript-filereader-.html#fbid=LLhCrL0KEb6

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 1 solution and 1 hack

SOLUTION:
Extending the split the data in chunks: it boils down to http protocol. REST parts on the notion that http has enough "language" for most client-server scenarios.

You can setup on the client a request header Content-len to establish how much data you need per request

Then on the backend have some options http://httpstatus.es

- Reply a 413 if the server is simply unable to get that much data from the db
- 417 if the server is able to reply but not under the requested header (Content-len)
- 206 with the provided chunk, letting know the client "there is more from where that came from"

HACK:
Use Websocket and get the binary file. Then use the html5 FileAPI to load it into memory.
This is likely to fail though because its not the download causing the problem, but the parsing of an almost-endless JS object

Answer (score 0):

You're out of luck on the browser. Not only do you have to download the file, but you'll have to parse the json regardless. Parse it on the server, break it into smaller chunks, store that data into the db, and query for what you need.